# Configuring a WCF Client to Use UserName Credentials On the Request and Check Certificate Credentials On the Response

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-client

I'm trying to use WCF to consume a web service provided by a third-party's Oracle Application Server. I pass a username and password in a UsernameToken as part of the request and as part of the response the web service returns a standard security tag in the header which includes a digest and signature.

With my current setup, I successfully send a request to the server and the web service sends the expected response data back. However, when parsing the response WCF throws a MessageSecurityException, with an InnerException.Message of "Supporting token signatures not expected."

My guess is that WCF wants me to configure it to handle the signature and verify it. I have a certificate from the third party that hosts the web service that I should be able to use to verify the signature, although I'm not sure if I'll need it.

Here's a sample header from a response that makes WCF throw the exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <dsig:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <dsig:SignedInfo>
          <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <dsig:Reference URI="#_51IUwNWRVvPOcz12pZHLNQ22">
            <dsig:Transforms>
              <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <dsig:DigestValue>
              [DigestValue here]
            </dsig:DigestValue>
          </dsig:Reference>
          <dsig:Reference URI="#_dI5j0EqxrVsj0e62J6vd6w22">
            <dsig:Transforms>
              <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <dsig:DigestValue>
              [DigestValue here]
            </dsig:DigestValue>
          </dsig:Reference>
        </dsig:SignedInfo>
        <dsig:SignatureValue>
          [Signature Value Here]
        </dsig:SignatureValue>
        <dsig:KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#BST-9nKWbrE4LRv6maqstrGuUQ22" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </dsig:KeyInfo>
      </dsig:Signature>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="BST-9nKWbrE4LRv6maqstrGuUQ22" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        [Security Token Here]
      </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="_dI5j0EqxrVsj0e62J6vd6w22" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2010-05-26T18:46:30Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body wsu:Id="_51IUwNWRVvPOcz12pZHLNQ22" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    [Body content here]
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My binding configuration looks like:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="myBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I think that basically what I have to do is configure WCF to use UserName client credentials in the request and Certificate client credentials in the response. I don't know how to do this though.

I'm new at WCF, so I'm sorry if this is a bit of a dumb question. I've been trying to Google solutions, but there seem to be so many different ways to configure WCF that I'm getting overwhelmed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I was able to work around this problem by creating a CustomMessageEncoder (with help from [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx)) to intercept the response message before WCF was able to handle it. There, I removed the BinarySecurityToken and Signature elements from the response before handing it off to WCF. I used the following method to remove the offending elements from the stream:

```
    private Stream RemoveSignatures(Stream stream)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(stream);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("dsig", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

        XmlNode signatureNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/dsig:Signature", nsMgr);
        XmlNode binarySecurityTokenNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security/wsse:BinarySecurityToken", nsMgr);
        XmlNode headerNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/wsse:Security", nsMgr);

        headerNode.RemoveChild(signatureNode);
        headerNode.RemoveChild(binarySecurityTokenNode);

        return new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(doc.OuterXml));
    }
```

Obviously this is not the greatest solution. It's very 'hacky'. But it works and if need be I can continue using it because the message security is already being taken care of by HTTPS transport.

If anyone can tell me a better way to solve this, I'm open.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like service isn't waiting for credentials at a place you providing them. Try to specify username and password for transport level instead.

Comment: The service accepts my credentials in the message with the way I have it set up now. I send the request and WCF receives the correct response. The problem is with WCF failing to deal with the signature in the response.